# PHP Date Calculator Returning Wrong Days

Tags: php, date

I'm using the below calculator to determine the years, months, and days between a set date and the current date. I thought it was working fine, but then it came up on the year mark and i noticed it was not working properly. Tomorrow is actually when the one year mark would be, but it is currently returning `11 months, 34 days`. Could anyone tell me whats wrong? It should be `11 months, 30 days`.

```
function relationshipTimer($functionDate)
{
    $date1 = $functionDate;
    $date2 = date("Y-m-d");
    $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
    $years = floor($diff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $months = floor(($diff - ($years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / ((365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 12));
    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60 * 24));
    if ($years > 0) {echo $years . " Year";}
    if ($years > 1) {echo "s ";}
    if ($months > 0) {echo " " . $months . " Month";}
    if ($months > 1) {echo "s ";}
    if ($date1 == $date2) {echo "1 Day ";}
    if ($days > 0) {echo $days . " Day";}
    if ($days > 1) {echo "s ";}
}
```

And this is where $functionDate comes from:

`relationshipTimer("2018-04-28");`

Comment: When I run this I get `1 Year` as the output for `relationship_timer("2018-04-28");`. You get `11 months, 34 days`?

Comment: Yep. But the below answer made sense out of why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you calculate `$days`, you are assuming that all months are 30 days long, which is obviously wrong. Therefore you get a year that is 11 months plus 35 days (36 days for leap years).

Processing dates is complicated. You should always use specialized tools like PHP's [`DateTime::diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

For example, with:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2018-04-28");
$date2 = new DateTime("2019-04-27");
$diff = $date2->diff($date1);
print $diff->format("%y years %m months %d days\n");
```

... you get (because April has 30 days):

```
0 years 11 months 29 days
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense and i didn't even realize that.

Comment: Use the functions/methods offered by PHP; see my example.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for the clarification and a way better working method.